# How I can wait for an expected value on magento cart page with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I try to wait with selenium webdriver for the calculated grand totals on the cart page before I trigger the next click event. But I got a exception. I have no other element on the page that I could wait for. I think it's really easy to find a solution for expierenced developers but I'm not the one.

I use this wait command:

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.cssSelector(".grand.totals .price"), "35,75 €"));`
```

This is the source code snippet who I tries to select the element.

```
<tr class="grand totals">
    <th class="mark" scope="row">
        <strong data-bind="i18n: title">Bestellsumme</strong>
    </th>
    <td data-bind="attr: {'data-th': title}" class="amount" data-th="Bestellsumme">
        <strong><span class="price" data-bind="text: getValue()">35,75&nbsp;€</span></strong>
    </td>
</tr>
```

This is the exception did I got.

> org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not interactable
>         (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
>         (Driver info: chromedriver=74.0.3729.6 (255758eccf3d244491b8a1317aa76e1ce10d57e9-refs/branch-heads/3729@{#29}),platform=Windows NT 10.0.17134 x86_64) (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>       Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
>       Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
>       System info: host: 'MARCEL-THINK', ip: '10.110.12.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '11.0.3'
>       Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver

Comment: According to exception any other element overplayed the target element, is this element present after any progress bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you were close. The text **35,75 €** includes a *space* character in between and is within a `<span>` tag. So you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.cssSelector("tr.grand.totals td.amount>strong>span.price"), "35,75"));
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated(By.xpath("//tr[@class='grand totals']//td[@class='amount']/strong/span[@class='price']"), "35,75"));
  ```